# Image loading slow while using Glide4 in RecyclerView to load images from url

Tags: java, android, groovy

I'm using **Glide** (4.6.1) for loading image from url to **RecyclerView** and it is very slow compared to apps like Amazon or flipkart, my each image size is approx **170 KB**. I don't want to use cache because I won't get dynamic response.  Is there any way to make the image loading faster.

```
public static void setGlide(Context context, ImageView imageView, String imageLink) {

         RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
            .skipMemoryCache(true)
            .centerCrop()
            .dontAnimate()
            .dontTransform()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.error_logo)
            .priority(Priority.IMMEDIATE)
            .encodeFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG)
            .format(DecodeFormat.DEFAULT);

    Glide.with(context)
            .applyDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
            .load(imageLink")
            .error(Glide.with(context)
                    .load(R.drawable.error_logo))
      .into(imageView);
    Glide.get(context).clearMemory();
}
```

**build.gradle** dependencies is

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
}
```

Comment: It will take time to load image from url you can use Placeholder to display image while loading.

Comment: Could you add your adapter class as well?

Comment: 170kb for an image displayed on mobile is a lot TBH. it should be around 50kb at max and for tablets it could go upto 100k. If it's(the app) not about image quality then try reducing it. Or maybe give users an option to choose image quality. But this will create overhead on backend as you have to keep all the images.

Comment: Try to add .override(width, height) in your RequestOptions and choose such width and height that you are satisfied with the image quality and load speed.

Comment: I have reduced my image size with in  1 Kb to 5 Kb, image loads faster but image quality is bad...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Problem is with this line :

```
 Glide.get(context).clearMemory();
```

You don't need to do it, glide automatically clears the cache. Read this :

> Although it’s good practice to clear loads you no longer need, you’re
>   not required to do so. In fact, Glide will automatically clear the
>   load and recycle any resources used by the load when the Activity or
>   Fragment you pass in to Glide.with() is destroyed.

You are clearing the cache at the loading time, which does not allow glide to load image from cache,which in turn load the image everytime from the internet. If you want to remove caching, Call this function when activity/fragment/view is destroys.

Try removing the that redundant line as glide does that task for you,after that check if that resolves your issue.

To make loading faster try using cache by setting DiskCacheStrategy from `DiskCacheStrategy.NONE` to `DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC` by following code.

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
            .skipMemoryCache(true)
            .centerCrop()
            .dontAnimate()
            .dontTransform()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.error_logo)
            .priority(Priority.IMMEDIATE)
            .encodeFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG)
            .format(DecodeFormat.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: I have modified the code as you have specified but there was only a small improvement...
thanks for the feedback

Comment: The image  takes long time to load the first time. after  that the image loads faster,is it being cached.. is there any alternative code to load image faster image without being cached?

Comment: Because you are using caching, therefore it's taking long time to load on first request, after that it will fetch images from cache only, which will reduce the loading time. you can use placeholder to in order to see the progress of the loading.

Comment: Is there any alternative code to load image faster without being cached...

Comment: You can clear the caching and Change DiskCacheStrategy to NONE , this will remove the caching and will call the request every time you want to load the image. I suggest you to not do that, because performance will reduce. Go with the caching there's no harm in it. you can use placeholder if you like to make UI good and image loading less boring.

Comment: How to notify Glide and update image when  image changed  from web without changing link

Answer (score 1):

```
Glide.with( context )
            .load( arrayList.get().getImage_url())
            .thumbnail( 0.5f )
            .override( 200, 200 )
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image)
            .diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.ALL )
            .into( imageView );
```